# grails 3 google authentication

Tags: grails, google-oauth

I looked at these examples:
[http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/integration-with-google-using-grails-oauth-plugin/](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/integration-with-google-using-oauth2-grails-oauth-plugin/)

http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/integration-with-google-using-oauth2-grails-oauth-plugin/

I can not connect to the specified plugin

```
compile ":oauth:2.1.0"
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'testGrails12'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
>   >     Could not resolve :oauth:2.1.0.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          testgrails12:testGrails12:0.1
>   >     Could not resolve :oauth:2.1.0.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core//oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core//oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom'.
>   >     Connect to repo.grails.org:443 [repo.grails.org/35.186.234.57] failed: Connection timed out: connect

How can i fix it? I am ready to consider other authentication options.

---

Use this [exemple](https://github.com/MatrixCrawler/grails-spring-security-oauth2-google).

> CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 9.161 secs |Running application... 2017-04-06 19:02:55.234
>   ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     :
>   Destroy method on bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
>   threw an exception
>
> |Running application... 2017-04-10 01:16:01.501 ERROR --- [
>   main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on
>   bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
>   threw an exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not
>   initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the
>   context:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@532721fd:
>   startup date [Mon Apr 10 01:15:59 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>     at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at testgrails12.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
>
> 2017-04-10 01:16:01.519 ERROR --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in
>   testgrails12.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]:
>   Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception;
>   nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed
>   to initialize class
>   [grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth2.SpringSecurityOAuth2Controller]
>   from plugin [springSecurityOauth2] :
>   grails/plugin/springsecurity/ControllerMixin  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>     at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at testgrails12.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]:
>   Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception;
>   nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed
>   to initialize class
>   [grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth2.SpringSecurityOAuth2Controller]
>   from plugin [springSecurityOauth2] :
>   grails/plugin/springsecurity/ControllerMixin  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 23 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class
>   [grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth2.SpringSecurityOAuth2Controller]
>   from plugin [springSecurityOauth2] :
>   grails/plugin/springsecurity/ControllerMixin  at
>   org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:175)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:104)
>     at
>   grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.createBinaryGrailsPlugin(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:375)
>     at
>   grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.findCorePlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:362)
>     at
>   grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.attemptLoadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:314)
>     at
>   grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
>     at
>   grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:89)
>     at
>   grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:225)
>     at
>   grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:77)
>     at
>   grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:69)
>     at
>   testgrails12.Application.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(Application.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 24 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   grails/plugin/springsecurity/ControllerMixin  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:173)
>     ... 40 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.ControllerMixin  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 56 common
>   frames omitted
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Error | Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You specified wrong plugin name. 
Try to use:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2:1.1.0'
```

in build.gradle.

Tutorial you provide is not for Grails 3, but for Grails 2. 
Please take a look at http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/matrixcrawler/spring-security-oauth2.

Comment: I looked at this example: [link](https://github.com/MatrixCrawler/grails-spring-security-oauth2-google). Your link led me to it. The plugins are connected, but when I run it I get an error.

Comment: Please, provide the exception stacktrace.

Comment: @PavelSavchick Look above